# Why is Google Chrome getting 400 errors when I try to load any content from a Phoenix server?

Tags: google-chrome, phoenix-framework

I'm currently trying to get a Phoenix project up and running, but my normal browser for dev (Chrome) is malforming all requests for some reason and just gets 400's form the server. I can see the default splash page in all other browsers, and Incognito mode, but I would like to be able to just use Chrome.

So far I have tried:

- Clearing browser cache, cookies, etc.
- Turning off all of my Chrome extensions and reloading Chrome.
- Running the server on different ports (4000, 4001, 3000, 3005, 8080)

This is the gist of what my errors are looking like in Chrome.

```
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:4000/ 400 (Bad Request)
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:4000/favicon.ico 400 (Bad Request)
```

Here's one example of a server that is giving me trouble:

```
https://github.com/phoenix-examples/hello_phoenix
```

Does anyone have prior experience with this or know of what I could try to get Chrome to play nice with Phoenix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selecting "since the beginning of time" option under `Chrome > Clear Browsing Data...` and clearing all data again fixed it!

Comment: I recently started seeing this problem a lot in my angular app served from localhost.  Clearing the browser data helps,  but I still want to find out what's the root cause of this.